# How can $\lim_{n\to \infty} (3^n + 4^n)^{1/n} = 4$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

If $\lim_{n\to \infty} (3^n + 4^n)^{1/n} = 4$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} 3^n + 4^n=\lim_{n\to \infty}4^n$ which implies that $\lim_{n\to \infty} 3^n=0$ which is clearly not correct. I tried to do the limit myself, but I got $3$. The way I did is that at the step $\lim_{n\to \infty} 3^n + 4^n=\lim_{n\to \infty}L^n$ I divided everything by $4^n$, and got $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac{3}{4})^n + 1=\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac{L}{4})^n$. Informally speaking, the $1$ on the LHS is going to be very insignificant as $n \rightarrow \infty$, so $L$ would have to be $3$. Could someone explain to me why am I wrong and how can the limit possibly be equal to $4$? Thanks!

Comment: Check again - "informally speaking", which is bigger, $(\frac34)^n$ or $1$?

Comment: $\lim_n (a_n+b_n)=\lim_n a_n+\lim_n b_n$ only applies when $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are convergent sequences.

Comment: @Macavity of course the $(\frac34)^n$, but I don't see your point.

Comment: Well, then you need to check once more.  It is NOT bigger, and as $n \rightarrow \infty$, LHS becomes $1$.

Comment: @Macavity Oh haha I can't believe that I didn't realize that 3/4<1, thanks for that. And of course it's obvious now that L=4

Comment: @Macavity However, if Stefan Hansen's statement is true, then how come my approach of dividing both sides worked? Was it a coincidence?

Comment: @Ovi: +1 and haha :D

Comment: That approach resulted in an equation which has only convergent terms.  Hence it held true.

Comment: @Macavity Oh ok thank you.

Comment: @Ovi You should use two dollar signs before and after equations or whatever you want to show emphasis on -and it looks much cleaner. :]

Comment: @euclid Oh ok I forgot about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\infty-\infty$ is not well-defined.

Comment: But you do not exactly have $\infty-\infty$. Altough the values are growing larger and larger, $4^n$ is a well defined real number for any large n, so I don't see why the rules of arithmetic wouldn't apply.

Comment: What would you say that $\lim_{n\to\infty} 4^n$ is?

Comment: ok i have no choice but to agree haha