# Raising each side of a limit to a power?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

If you have $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=L$ $\quad$(or as $x \rightarrow c$ for that matter), is it correct to say that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)^{g(x)}=L^{\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)}$ as long as $L \not= 1$? I'm not looking for a very rigorous response, I am just looking for if this is a correct technique in general that can help you evaluate a limit. Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419882/prove-the-following-limit-lim-n-to-infty-3n-4n1-n-4/420010#420010) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419999/how-can-lim-n-to-infty-3n-4n1-n-4) are related to Ovi's question.

Comment: You want to look up indeterminate forms. If $L\neq 0,1$ is a real positive number, and $g(x)$ tends to a real positive number, then your equation is true. If, say, $L=0$ and $g(x)\to\infty$, then you have to evaluate the limit some other way; there are examples such that the limit can be any positive real value, or not even exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the comment discussion where the question arose.

I will give a sequence of more or less trivial cases.

The most easiest case is to ask whether 
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)=f(\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n)$$
holds. This is always the case when $f$ is continuous and might be true even if $f$ is not continuous.

the next case is to ask whether 
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x_n)= \lim_{k\to \infty} f_k (\lim_{n\to \infty }(x_n))$$
holds. Here we need more than just every $f_k$ to be continous, we even need that the 
limit function ist continuous. This is always the case if $f_n$ converges uniformly.

In your case as 
$$ f(x)^{g(x)} = \exp(\log(f(x))\cdot g(x))$$
Here you see that the case where $f(x)$ goes to $1$ surely could cause trouble. Furthermore 
negative values of $f(x)$ has to be handled in a different way.

In the case where you question comes from you looked at the sequence of functions $x^n$. This converges pointwise on $[0,1]$ diverges everywhere else and converges uniform due to Dini's Theorem on $[0,1-\varepsilon]$. So whenever the limit is strictly lower than $1$ you may do it.

Comment: But even when the limit is greater than 1 you can still do it $most$ of the time, right?

Comment: no absolutely not. Because it diverges. Do be exakt it NEVER works when  the limit is greater than 1. Because $x^n$ doesn't have a limit at all whenever $x>1$

Comment: But it worked in $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (3^n + 4^n)^{1/n} = 4.$ See my answer, I assumed L is the limit, and I got L=4, which is correct. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419882/prove-the-following-limit-lim-n-to-infty-3n-4n1-n-4/420010#420010

Comment: Just because the result is correct doesn't mean the intermediate steps are correct