# finding the limit to $(3^n+5^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I was wondering if one can find the limit to the sequence $\{a_n\}$, where: $$\large a_n=(3^n+5^n)^{\large\frac{1}{n}}$$

Without the use of a calculator.

Comment: Hint: $5^n\le 3^n+5^n\le 2\cdot 5^n$.

Comment: This is a duplicate.

Comment: This has essentially been answered in the anwers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/440990)

Comment: Now consider what happens if you let $n\rightarrow 0^{+}$.  Can you solve that without l'Hospital's rule?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440990/when-can-you-treat-a-limit-like-an-equation

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hint: $5^n\le 3^n+5^n\le 2\cdot 5^n$.

Comment: Followed by squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 7):

$$(3^n+5^n)^{1/n} = 5 \left [ 1+\left (\frac{3}{5}\right )^n \right ]^{1/n}$$

$(3/5)^n \lt 1$ for $n \gt 0$ so that the sum approaches

$$5 \left [ 1 + \frac{1}{n} \left (\frac{3}{5}\right )^n  \right ] \to 5$$

as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

In the same way as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/441003),
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(3^n+5^n\right)^{1/n}
&=5\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(\frac35\right)^n+1\right)^{1/n}\\
&=5(0+1)^0\\[9pt]
&=5
\end{align}
$$